# Ideal way to identify encoding of a content in HTTP request?

Tags: rest, http, encoding, http-headers, mime

I have a need to develop REST-based API that can accept either binary or base64 encoded content, and possibly other contents. It has to require that the encoding of the file is identified; otherwise it is assumed to be binary. I don't want to auto-guess based on the contents of the API.

My first inclination was to use `Content-Type` but `base64` does not appear as one of well-known content types - makes sense since it's not really a type but rather a encoding.

Reading various RFC specs, one would think `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header is an appropriate place to indicate whether the content of the request body is encoded as a base64 or as binary. However, I do not think it is appropriate because it's primarily for SMTP protocols, where they are limited to 7 bits.

Then there's `Content-Encoding` or `Transfer-Encoding` but I don't see `base64` as a well-known value for that header because both headers have more to do with compressing the content rather than indicating whether base64 encoding has been applied.

I'm inclined to think that using custom headers is probably safest as to not breach any existing specs but wanted to see if nice folks at SO can come up with a good & definitive answer that will be compliant with the RFCs.

Comment: What's the point in supporting base64, when http is perfectly capable of doing binary???

Comment: Because I have clients who want to send base64 encoded content? Not saying HTTP can't do it; only that I need to not have to guess whether I have a base64 encoded content or whatever.

Comment: OK, so why do the *clients* want to base64-encode?